# "Not Enough Space on Disk" Error When Deploying React App to Azure App Service

Tags: azure

I've seen various posts of this same error where there's *"not enough disk space"* but I'm puzzled as to why I'd be getting it. My *React* app is very small, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this issue or how to find where the disk is being filled. I don't have any log files to my knowledge that would be taking up so much space.

I get this error deploying from VS Code or GitHub Actions.
The App Service Plan is **D1 (Shared)**

Comment: Can you try scaling your app service plan to B1 and retry the deployment

Comment: That worked, but is there a way to see what other items could be taking up so much space? When I looked at that app service, there was only 250mb of the 1gb being used and I believe the React app was 97mb. That's the only app on that service plan and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything before committing to $50+ a month just for solo development/testing.

Comment: Glad to know that your problem has been solved after scaling up. This might be an issue with the temporary files refer to [this documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) for more information about app service file system about persistent files and temporary files

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, using B1 plan. I am using a create react app.

Deployment Center's log said `Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\hbeedny5.zip (94.27 MB) to C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n`

I saw the comment and upgraded to B1, then saw this folder structure, with my node modules, in my deployed env.

[image: azure folder]

All you truly need is the [build folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/).

So I fixed my zip to only be the build folder.

```yaml
- name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip ./build/*
```

In azure I made sure to point to the `build` folder.
[image]

Then using azures *App Service Editor* you verify the folder structure on deployed.

[image]

The files were then publish correctly and I could change back to a B1 plan.

**Note**: you should be able to downgrade to B1 at any time and redeploy. The github action should clean our your dir for you and if you deploy just the `build` folder all you need is a `B1 sub`.

Comment: Just for my own understanding, you had to upgrade from B1 to a higher plan and then with the changes you made could go back down to B1?

Comment: Added a Note to address that comment. Lmk if this fixes the issue for you.