# Github actions - "There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n"

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have an app service running on Azure , I usually just push/merge/pr to my main branch and my Github Actions start doing all the work,  one day it stop working , building is success but when deploying  i am met with  "There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n"  I Have no clue why, and the weird part is that if i publish/deploy directly within my IDE (Rider) with Azure toolkit it works.

[image: Screenshot of failed Github Action deploy]

And the file system is not near full
[image: Azure app service file system]

Went to KUDU and did a check on storage
[image: KUDU disk space]

I know that i can upgrade the pricing plan to Basic B1 and that should give me 9 more GIG to play with but I dont see that the storage is the issue here according to the screenshot.

I tried to merge my staging branch into my main branch, i expected the build and deploy to success, but its only build that succeeded, deployment failed.

Comment: The standard GitHub-hosted runner has 14 GB of disk space, our you maybe hitting that limit?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [SO Thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053237/not-enough-space-on-disk-error-when-deploying-react-app-to-azure-app-service) by @VenkateshDodda. Yes, One option is to upgrade your  App service instance to B1 and redeploy your web app. This issue occurs due to the presence of Temporary files, Taking your space. as mentioned in the SO thread above.

Also, I see you are using .Net application for your deployment. Usually, These .Net example- Asp.net app takes more space and might not fit in the Free tier of the Web app, So its recommended to upgrade your App service tier to B1 and try the deployment again.

[image]

Try removing the unnecessary files form your source code and deploy the code again. If you want to make use of Temporary files too for the deployment, Add this setting - `WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION` and refer the same document for getting insights on the app file system in azure.

Also, as per the comment by **@Benjamin W**. If this issue is with github action limitation being reached. You can set the retention period of the build artifacts to 1 day instead of default 90 days. This setting will delete the generated build artifacts after 1 day instead of storing them for 90 days and consuming space, Which might cause your deployment to fail due to space errors.

***1) Set the retention days policy to 1 day from 90 days in your github action workflow setting like below:-***

[image]

***2) Delete all the previous build artifact like below:-***

[image]

**Reference:-**
[workflow - [GitHub Actions]: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730786/github-actions-create-artifact-container-failed-artifact-storage-quota-has-b)