# Bitbucket git failing to deploy to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket

Recently our BitBucket deploys to an Azure Web App have started failing with:

```
fatal: not enough memory for initialization\r\nC:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe remote add -t master origin "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy
```

I've tried re-authorising, removing the deployment connection, and re-adding, and nothing is fixing.

The size of the repo is only 1.1mb so it's not big!

Comment: How much memory are your Bitbucket runners configured to use?

Comment: I don't use runners at the moment - should I?  The Azure integration just auths with BitBucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer my SO thread answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632745/github-actions-there-is-not-enough-space-on-the-disk-r-n/76634578#76634578) to free up some space from your Azure Web app and github artifacts that gets stored for a longer time and try to push your changes again to deploy the web app via Bitbucket.

Cross check your Bitbucket plan and see if there's any remaining memory available:-

[image]

You can check your repository files and remove the large files by  running the commands below:-

```
git rev-list --objects --all 
git filter-branch
```

[image]

I cloned my bitbucket repo in my source code folder in Vs Code and ran the below commands to push the source code files from my local machine to bitbucket repository:-

```
git clone https://xxxxbitbucket@bitbucket.org/siddheshbitbucket56/pythonapp.git
git add .  
git pull origin master 
git commit . -m "my first git commit" 
git remote -v #checked if the bitbucket repository is added as remote if not run the command below:-
git remote add origin <bitbucket clone url>
git push -u oriigin master -f  #check if your bitbucket url is part of origin or oriigin or something else and use that in -u
```

Another option to push changes and to resolve your error is to refer this [**So thread answer**](https://serverfault.com/questions/372899/git-fails-to-push-with-error-out-of-memory) by Brian Swift

> ```
> git -c core.packedGitWindowSize=32m -c core.packedGitLimit=256m  push origin master
> ```

[image]

[image]

Additional [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203183/git-fatal-out-of-memory-malloc-failed-on-branch-push)

Repository got published to Bitbucket successfully like below:-

[image]

***In my Azure Web app > Selected Deployment Center > Source > Bitbucket > Authorized with Bitbucket by signing in with my bitbucket account like below:-***

[image]

I clicked on **Save** and the **Deployment was successful** like below:-

[image]

**I can browse my Web app:-**

[image]